# Payara Micro with enhanced classloading?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, payara-micro

I have a big war that gets built with a bunch of dependencies, including newer versions of guava, jackson etc. In order to get it to work on Payara Server 5.183, I have added a `glassfish-web.xml` file with the `<class-loader delegate="false"/>` tag to the WEB-INF folder of my war. This seems to work great in Payara Server and the war runs happily.

I would also like to be able to run my war with Payara Micro, so that it can be bundled up and shared with the team in a reproducible way. But when I use the exact same war and run:

`java -jar payara-micro-5.183.jar --deploy myapp.war --domainConfig domain-micro.xml --rootDir domain/`

I get the following error which sounds to me like it is probably a classloader issue (although it might not be, I'm happy to also take alternative suggestions):

```
java.lang.Exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not a subtype
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1:

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_191" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Full stacktrace:

```
INFO  Jsr330Integration:57 - Starting up JSR 330 integration
[2018-11-26T09:11:15.760+0000] [] [←[1;92mINFO←[0m] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [←[1;94mjavax.enterprise.web←[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1543223475760] [levelValue: 800] Loading application [MyApp] at [/MyApp]

[2018-11-26T09:11:15.761+0000] [] [←[1;93mWARNING←[0m] [AS-EJB-00056] [←[1;94mjavax.enterprise.ejb.container←[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=194 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool2] [timeMillis: 1543223475761] [levelValue: 900] A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB Jsr330Integration, method: publi
c java.lang.Object com.mypackage.bean.jsr330.Jsr330Integration.getInstance(java.lang.Class)

[2018-11-26T09:11:15.775+0000] [] [←[1;93mWARNING←[0m] [] [←[1;94mjavax.enterprise.ejb.container←[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=194 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool2] [timeMillis: 1543223475775] [levelValue: 900] [[

javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Jsr330Integration
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:736)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:438)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.checkInit(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:410)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer._getContext(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:183)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.CMCSingletonContainer._getContext(CMCSingletonContainer.java:116)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2627)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2020)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy302.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mypackage.bean.jsr330.__EJB31_Generated__Jsr330Integration__Intf____Bean__.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mypackage.manager.impl.VolumeClearingManager.setup(VolumeClearingManager.java:706)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1047)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:206)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:998)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:206)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:998)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:417)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:380)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2063)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:518)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:99)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:713)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:220)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:442)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2627)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2020)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy313.cancelOpenVolumeClearings(Unknown Source)
        at com.mypackage.manager.impl.__EJB31_Generated__VolumeClearingManager__Intf____Bean__.cancelOpenVolumeClearings(Unknown Source)
        at com.mypackage.bean.timer.event.handler.StartUpEventHandler.cancelOpenVolumeClearingProcesses(StartUpEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.mypackage.bean.timer.event.handler.StartUpEventHandler.handle(StartUpEventHandler.java:88)
        at com.mypackage.bean.timer.TimerBean.timeout(TimerBean.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:953)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1017)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4867)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4839)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4827)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4105)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1229)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:94)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1964)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Jsr330Integration
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:564)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:78)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:734)
        ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternalFromJars(WebappClassLoader.java:2908)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2761)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2651)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1067)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1624)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1505)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.<init>(Initializer.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.<init>(InternalInjectorCreator.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
        at com.mypackage.bean.jsr330.Jsr330Integration.setup(Jsr330Integration.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1047)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:206)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:998)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:206)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:998)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:417)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:380)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2063)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:555)
        ... 94 more
]]

[2018-11-26T09:11:15.847+0000] [] [←[1;92mINFO←[0m] [] [←[1;94mPayaraMicro←[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1543223475847] [levelValue: 800]
{
    "Instance Configuration": {
        "Host": "BS-DEV-75438.eu.ad.mycorp.com",
        "Http Port(s)": "8080",
        "Https Port(s)": "",
        "Instance Name": "Frail-Fusilier",
        "Instance Group": "MicroShoal",
        "Hazelcast Member UUID": "dddef61b-bd0c-4faa-9167-0e1ffee5730a",
        "Deployed": [
            {
                "Name": "MyApp",
                "Type": "war",
                "Context Root": "/MyApp"
            }
        ]
    }
}

[2018-11-26T09:11:15.894+0000] [] [←[1;91mSEVERE←[0m] [] [←[1;94mjavax.enterprise.ejb.container←[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=194 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool2] [timeMillis: 1543223475894] [levelValue: 1000] ejb.stateless_ejbcreate_exception
```

The class it can't load:

```
package com.mypackage.bean.jsr330;

import com.mypackage.bean.marketdata.MarketDataHandlerBean;
import com.mypackage.bean.notification.NotificationEngine;
import com.mypackage.bean.rankingdata.LpRankingUpdateHandlerBean;
import com.mypackage.eapi.context.Context;
import com.mypackage.eapi.marketdata.MarketDataHandler;
import com.mypackage.eapi.rankingdata.LpRankingUpdateHandler;
import com.mypackage.interfaces.bgc.integration.IntegrationModule;
import com.mypackage.persistence.dao.DaoHolder;
import com.mypackage.persistence.dao.LegalEntityDao;
import com.mypackage.persistence.dao.StrategyDao;
import com.mypackage.persistence.dao.UserDao;
import com.mypackage.persistence.dao.VolumeClearingDao;
import com.mypackage.persistence.redis.dao.RedisFuturePriceDao;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Key;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/*
 * A little utility to hide Guice implementation of jsr330 so we don't end up using guice specific
 * features
 */
@LocalBean
@Singleton
public class Jsr330Integration {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Jsr330Integration.class);

  private Injector injector;
  @Resource
  private ManagedExecutorService executor;
  @EJB
  private MarketDataHandlerBean marketDataHandler;
  @EJB
  private LpRankingUpdateHandlerBean marketMakerHandlerBean;
  @EJB
  private NotificationEngine notificationEngine;
  @EJB
  private TaskRunnerBean taskRunner;

  @PostConstruct
  public void setup() {
    LOG.info("Starting up JSR 330 integration");
    injector =
        Guice.createInjector(
            new IntegrationModule(),
            new AbstractModule() {
              @Override
              protected void configure() {
                bind(ExecutorService.class).toInstance(executor);
                bind(MarketDataHandler.class).toInstance(marketDataHandler);
                bind(LpRankingUpdateHandler.class).toInstance(marketMakerHandlerBean);
                bind(NotificationEngine.class).toInstance(notificationEngine);
                final DaoHolder instance = DaoHolder.getInstance();
                bind(StrategyDao.class).toInstance(instance.getStrategyDao());
                bind(RedisFuturePriceDao.class).toInstance(instance.getRedisFuturePriceDao());
                bind(UserDao.class).toInstance(instance.getUserDao());
                bind(LegalEntityDao.class).toInstance(instance.getLegalEntityDao());
                bind(VolumeClearingDao.class).toInstance(instance.getVolumeClearingDao());
                bind(TaskRunnerBean.class).toInstance(taskRunner);
              }
            });
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    LOG.info("Shutting down eapi context and all eapi services");
    injector.getInstance(Context.class).shutdownServices();
  }

  public <T> T getInstance(final Class<T> clazz) {
    return injector.getInstance(clazz);
  }

  public <T> T getInstance(final Key<T> var1) {
    return injector.getInstance(var1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace available for the exception, or was it just reported as an error message? Also, which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Hi @skomisa I've added the full stacktrace, java version and the class where it's failing - any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, no bright ideas. Since this is working fine for you on the latest version of a full Payara server I can only suggest [raising an issue on this with Payara](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jackson).

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed ?

Comment: @PaulNUK no sadly not